Running PHPSpreadsheet via crontab on DigitalOcean - not saving
When I run the following script via a browser using the URL, all emails are sent, the XLSX is saved where it should be and the result is very quick.
However, when it runs via crontab, it sends me the first two emails but not the last one and it doesn't save the XLSX file, making me believe there's an error at this point.
Unfortunately I don't get any error messages in the log file.
<?php

require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/includes/mail.php';

//SEND AN EMAIL TO ME: "STARTED CRON"

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$newsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet($spreadsheet, "My first sheet");
$spreadsheet->addSheet($newsheet);

$activesheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndexByName("My first sheet");
$activesheet->getTabColor()->setRGB("FF0000");
$activesheet->setCellValue("A1", "Test");
$activesheet->setCellValue("A2", "Some numbers...");
$activesheet->setCellValue("A3", 1);
$activesheet->setCellValue("A4", 2);
$activesheet->setCellValue("A5", "=SUM(A3:A4)");

$activesheet->getStyle("A1")->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$activesheet->getStyle("A1")->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB("FFC6EFCE"); //LIGHT GREEN

//SEND AN EMAIL TO ME: "SET THE DATA"

$destinationfile = "/folder/to/file/TEST_FILE.xlsx";
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save($destinationfile);

//SEND AN EMAIL TO ME: "FINISHED CRON"

I'm currently using DigitalOcean as my server with PHP Version 8.2.13 and the composer.json file says:
{
    "require": {
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.29",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.9.1"
    }
}


I don't get any error messages in the log file...is error logging enabled for command-line PHP in that environment? Have you done any other debugging - e.g. adding your own logging to the script so you can see exactly where it gets to, and what values any relevant variables have got at that moment? There's really not a lot we can do for you based on such minimal information. If the code works in one context but not another, the issue is most likely its environment rather than the code itself - e.g. something permissions related, or timing, or something like that.

@ADyson you were right, it was permissions... it wasn't erroring on browser because the folder's user is fine at those permissions.  However, the crontab needs full permissions.  Changign the folder has worked and I really should have thought about this before posting on here!
